# Closed form for $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{n}x^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I want to find the generating function of the following recurrence relation

$$ a_n = \binom{k}{n} $$

I already know that in the case of $a_n=\binom{n}{k}$, the generating function $A(x)$ can be given as

$$ \begin{align*}
A(z)&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^n\\
&=&\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^{k+1}}
\end{align*}$$

How do I do this in the case that I am choosing n element from k?

Thanks!!

Comment: Unless $k$ varies as well, it will just be a polynomial (since $\binom{k}{n}=0$ for $n>k$).

Comment: Well how did you obtain the generating function in the other case? Try examining the method used in that case and see how to modify it for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{n}x^n\\
= \sum_{n=0}^{k}\binom{k}{n}x^n 1^{k-n}\\
=(1+x)^k$$